# How can I get the deleted file name using Microsoft graph's delta query

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-files

I am running a delta query against SharePoint site drive root. For the removed files I am just getting "deleted" property and DriveItem Id and the name property is always null. Whenever doing a separate DriveItem request with the corresponding DriveItem Id for the removed file getting 404. Any ideas on how can we retrieve the properties of the deleted file?

Comment: Which API endpoint are you calling? Is it `/sites/{siteId}/drive/root/delta`?

Comment: I am using c# sdk and yes, it's using that endpoint.

Comment: Would you please provide us with an update on the status of your issue?

Comment: Hi @CarlZhao. Seems Saad's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75800177/1684390) is the only possible way to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

i am having the same issue, one solution could be having a separate list with all items's names and ids, and then after using the delta query that returns the ids, you can then compare it with the ids from that list and get the name of the item